# User not redircted back to last visited page after logged out

Tags: php, redirect, cookies

In my website I am trying to redirect uers back to the last page they visited after they log back in but I am not getting it. I used cookie to track their last visited page, and I created a redirect page to check if the cookie still exist and if it does it should take them to the last page they left off.

here is the header of my website which I included to all the pages:

```
include('../includes/admins.php');  

// Set your cookie before redirecting to the login page
$current_page = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$_COOKIE['redirect_to'] = $current_page;

$cookie_name = $_COOKIE['redirect_to'];
$cookie_value = $current_page;
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
     <meta name="description" content="Automating your school work.">
    <meta name="author" content="<?php echo $set['siteName']; ?>">
    <meta name="keyword" content="content, management, system, schools, school management system, schoool portal, chat, link, linkedln, <?php echo $set['siteName']; ?>">
    <link rel="icon"  href="<?php echo $set['installUrl'].'logo/'.$set['schoolLogo']; ?>" type="image" />
    <title><?php echo $fullname;  ?></title>
    <!-- Favicon-->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="images/apple-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="images/apple-icon-60x60.png">
     <link rel="manifest" href="images/manifest.json">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="images/ms-icon-144x144.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="">
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="../afiles/css/font.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../afiles/css/icon.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="../afiles/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css">
    <!-- Bootstrap Core Css -->
    <link href="../afiles/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../afiles/css/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.css" />
</head>
```

If you look at the top you will see I include the cookie.

Here is the redirect page to see if cookie exist:

```
<?php
include('../includes/functions.php');

if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    header("Location: main");
} else {
    header("Location: ". $cookie_name);
}

?>
```

Need someone to point me to the right direction.

Comment: `$cookie_name` might be undefined in second block of code.

Comment: @GytisTenovimas, Yes you're right. I echo the value in login page but it gives  Notice: Undefined variable: cookie_value in C:\wamp\www\totallight\i_admin\sign-in.php on line 5. What do you think I can do?

Comment: Since now it's clear why it doesn't work, I can answer to your question how to fix this problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second block of code you have `$_COOKIE[$cookie_name]` but since you haven't defined `$cookie_name` in your file, `!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])` will always return `false`. Possible solutions:

Replace

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
```

with

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['redirect_to'])) {
```

To match the index value of the first block code.

Second option, if you think you might change `redirect_to` value, is to [define](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) a constant in a separate file and then use it in both of your blocks.